# A naturalistic view of Trimurti

Tags: shiva, vishnu, brahma, gunas, vaisheshika

I am a Vaishnava, and I am in no way converting just satisfying my curiosity. Does any non-Vedantic Darshana have later works that try and view Brahma, Vishnu, and Shiva as creative, preservative, and destructive forces of nature? As well as simple figurative or deification of the tri-guna concept. If so, please provide sources I want old works, not new modern works.